# c++ how to read this creating new constructor code?

Tags: c++

```
LinkedListNode* toSort = new LinkedListNode((MTNode*)0, (LinkedListNode*)0,
        (LinkedListNode*)0);
```

can someone give me detail explanation on how to read this code??
especially, I don't understand those zeros in

```
(MTNode*)0, (LinkedListNode*)0,(LinkedListNode*)0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a bit more modern c++, it would look like:

```
LinkedListNode* toSort = new LinkedListNode(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Does it make more sense now? It just passes null values for each expected pointer.

Comment: will it be okay to have 

    LinkedListNode* toSort = new LinkedListNode(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

and then 

    auto list = toSort;
    list = new LinkedListNode(ptr1, ptr2, ptr3);

is this okay?

Comment: @JinJung: In terms of syntax and type? Yes. But it seems odd to copy the pointer only to overwrite it immediately thereafter. Are you sure that's what you intended to do?

Comment: @JinJung, I feel we are treading in dangerous water here. Don't use variables without initializing them. Regardless, if you have further questions about programming, post them as separate SO questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I was referring to Jin Jungs comment *" 
Oh I could just use it without really initializing it"*, which didn't bode well for me.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Sorry I don't even know how I didn't absorb that having _just_ read it. Bah!

Answer (score 3):

Literal 0 designates a nullpointer where a pointer is expected. The casts to the relevant pointer types are ¹redundant. In modern C++ just write `nullptr`, and preferably use curly braces for constructor invocations, i.e.

```
auto* toSort = new LinkedListNode{ nullptr, nullptr, nullptr };
```

---

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ Unless there are two or more overloads that accept literal 0 arguments; in that case the casts can serve to disambiguate the call, choose the right constructor.</sup>

Comment: Or just `auto`.

Comment: how would auto* and auto make difference?
will it be same?

Comment: @JinJung: Technically they yield the same type in the end. `auto*` signals explicitly to the reader that it's a pointer type. Cost: 1 extra character. But that info is also readily available from the `new`-expression. So it's a question of style and personal preference. I like the explicitness, and some others like the conciseness of just `auto`.

Comment: If you're using `auto` it's because you don't want to bother signifying what type it is. `auto*` is _really_ hedging your bets...

Comment: The casts aren't necessarily redundant, they may be for disambiguation.

Comment: I just accepted the first one to comment... sorry.. but yours was also very helpful!! thank you!!

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Thanks! I didn't think of that in this context. Added a footnote about it.